# Events and selectors in native javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can this jQuery-dependent code

```
$('.myElement').click(function () {
  drawMode = !drawMode;
  $icon = $(this).children('i');
  if (drawMode) {
    $icon.removeClass('a').addClass('b');
  } else {
    $icon.removeClass('b').addClass('a');
  }
});
```

be rewritten into native javascript?

**I have tried**

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('myElement')[0];    
element.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  drawMode = !drawMode;
  var icon = this.children()[0];
  if (drawMode) {
    icon.classList.remove('a').add('b');
  } else {
    icon.classList.remove('b').add('a');
  }
});
```

but I cannot find the children element correctly.

Comment: "native JavaScript" => "using the DOM API"

Comment: Use `childNodes` instead of `children()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's `children` allows you to filter by selector, something that isn't in the DOM API (you can find all *descendants* matching a given CSS selector, but you can't [for now] limit it to just children).

If it doesn't matter whether it's a child or just any descendant, then:

```
var icon = this.querySelector("i");
```

That finds the first descendant within the element that's an `i` element. I suspect that would work just fine for you. The only time it might not would be if you had this:

```
<div class="myElement">
    <span>
        <i>You DON'T want this one</i>
    </span>
    <i>You do want this one</i>
</div>
```

If that's the case and you need to only look at children, not all descendants, you'll need a loop:

```
var icon = null;
var n;
for (n = 0; n < !icon && this.children.length; ++n) {
    if (this.children[n].tagName.toLowerCase() === "i") {
        icon = this.children[n];
    }
}
```

In ES2015+ (you can transpile to use it today), that's so much tidier:

```
let icon = Array.from(this.children)
                .find(child => child.tagName.toLowerCase() === "i");
```

Comment: What's the difference between a child and a descendant? Can a descendant also be the `<i>` element in `<div class="myElement"></div><i class="a"></i>`?

Comment: @Jamgreen: No, that's a *sibling*. All children are descendants, but not all descendants are children, some are children of children, or even deeper. E.g.: `<div><span><i></i></span></div>` The `span` is a child (and descendant) of the `div`. The `i` is a descendant (but not child) of the `div`. In your example, your `i` is a child element of the `div`. `querySelector` will find it just fine.

Comment: @Jamgreen That `i` wouldn't be a descendant. It would be a sibling.

Comment: @Jamgreen: *"What's the difference between a child and a descendant?"* It's like in real life. Your grandchildren are your descendants, not your children. And your siblings are not your children or descendants either.

Comment: @JLRishe: Well-spotted, I misread it. (Hit my vote limit for the day.)

Comment: @Jamgreen: But if that were your structure, the jQuery code you've quoted wouldn't find that `i` either.

Answer (score 2):

A few notes:

1. The `add` and `remove` functions of the `classList` **do not** return the `classList` object, so you can't concatenate them (`e.add().remove()`, like you are used to do in jQuery).
2. In your code you only go over the first element, while when using jQuery the changes are made for all elements that you selected.
3. I used the `querySelectorAll` and filtered out elements that are not direct childs, (checked for the `parentElement` since you used the `children()` function of jQuery).

Here is an example:

```js
drawMode = true;
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myElement');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var that = this;
    drawMode = !drawMode;
    var icons = this.querySelectorAll('i');
    for (var j = 0; j < icons.length; j++) {
      var icon = icons[j];
      if (icon.parentElement != that) {
        continue;
      }
      if (drawMode) {
        icon.classList.remove('a');
        icon.classList.add('b');
      } else {
        icon.classList.remove('b')
        icon.classList.add('a');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
i.a {
  background: red;
}
i.b {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myElement">
  <i>asd</i><br />
  <i>fgh</i><br />
  <span><i>This element will not change because he isn't a direct child</i></span><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is very useful when converting jQuery to vanilla javascript.

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

```js
// get a NodeList of elements which match CSS Selector '.myElement'
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.myElement');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
  // loop through every element with class 'myElement'
  var element = elements[i];

  element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    drawMode = !drawMode;

    var icon = element.querySelector('i');
    if (drawMode) {
      icon.classList.remove('a');
      icon.classList.add('b');
    } else {
      icon.classList.remove('b');
      icon.classList.add('a');
    }
  });
}
```

Note I've also used [`element.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to match descendants of the currently processed element.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!